# Removing first array for json output

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have got a simple function which outputs an array which i can then just "json_encode" This works fine. But now i need to do this multiple times.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsol)) {
                    $all[] = jsonoutput("$row[appid]");
}
```

But when i json_encode($all) this, it will have a first "header" sort of speak. Which i dont want.

What i get now (showing a sample part)

```
[
  - {
      - Firstentry: {
    info1: "bla",
    info2: "bla2",
        cell {
            color: "green",
```

But what i want is:

```
{
      - Firstentry: {
    info1: "bla",
    info2: "bla2",
        cell {
            color: "green",
```

I see 2 possible sollutions, the json_encode should start 1 level deeper/lower (always mix those up) or the first array should be removed before the json_encode.

Either way, i am lost in between the 2. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE: added array output:

Good:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["Firstentry"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (11) { ["info1"]=> string(3) "bla" ["info2"]=> string(3) "bla2"
```

Wrong:

```
array(63) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["Firstentry"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (10) { ["info1"]=> string(3) "bla" ["info2"]=> string(3) "bla2"
```

p.s. the function is called above jsonoutput, but this just outputs an array, i json_encode it in the end.

Comment: `json_encode` should only be called *once*.  Create your array, then `json_encode` the entire thing once at the end.

Comment: as in the update above, its only a function that i call. I do json_encode "after" the loop has filled the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by changing it into:

```
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultsol)) {
                    $output = jsonoutput("$row[appid]");
                    $all = array_merge($all, (array) $output);
            }
```

Then doing the json_encode.